# Android Fragment Collect SharedFlow from Shared ViewModel Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

Currently I have a `ViewPager2` Fragment (as the start destination), which holds two child Fragments: `ActiveOrderFragment` and `CompletedOrderFragment`, they both have their own `ViewModel`s to handle the api calls (to get the active orders and completed orders).

When the user clicks on the order item it will navigate to `OrderEditorFragment`, and there is a "Set Item as Active/Completed" button, clicking on that will update the status of the order (just simply a **PUT** request), and go back to the `ViewPager2` Fragment.

In order to notify & refresh `ActiveOrderFragment` and `CompletedOrderFragment`, I created a `SharedFlow` in `OrderViewModel`, which is a shared `ViewModel`:

```
class OrderViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val uiScope = viewModelScope
    private val _isOrderStatusChanged = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(replay = 1)          

    val isOrderStatusChanged: SharedFlow<Boolean>
        get() = _isOrderStatusChanged

    fun updateIsOrderStatusChanged() = _isOrderStatusChanged.emit(uiScope, true)            
}
```

Then I observe (collect) this `SharedFlow` in `onCreateView()` of `ActiveOrderFragment` and `CompletedOrderFragment`:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
        orderViewModel.isOrderStatusChanged.collect { 
            if (it) {
                Log.v("xxx", "refreshed!")
                viewModel.refreshActiveOrders()    //similar in CompletedOrderFragment
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes the issue: when I changed the status and go back to the pages, they both get notified and refreshed. However, now I click on any order item to go to the editor page but do nothing, and go back, the `collect{}` gets called again, which is not an expected behavior. How to prevent that? I guess that's relevant to the `replay` property...

---

Some extra info:

1. [Why use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `lifecycleScope` directly.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67422182/3466808)
2. [Why need `replay = 1` for `SharedFlow`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70262955/3466808)

Comment: you need to reset isOrderStatusChanged to false after you consumed OrderStatusChanged event.

Comment: @CTD If I really need to do "manually reset" I would choose `StateFlow` instead of `SharedFlow`, I choose `SharedFlow` because it's designed for one-time event.

Comment: If you want to trigger it once, change to `replay = 0`

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestine That means you didn't read my last link, I have to set that to 1.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(replay = 1) == MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
```

what is means replay

`MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(replay = 0)` catch nothing

`MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(replay = 1)` catch latest value

`MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(replay = 2)` catch latest 2 value

```
orderViewModel.isOrderStatusChanged.collect {
            Log.i("isOrderStatusChanged","$it")
        }
```

if you set _isOrderStatusChanged twice with diff value, you will find out.

Comment: I have already provided the reason why I need to set `replay` to 1, you can check out the last link.